# Fuelphp Upload 2 kinds of file on the same controller or model

Tags: php, fuelphp

I am using Fuelphp Upload Class for along time. But this is the first time
I am going to save 2 types of file on the same controller. First file
is an image, the second is a CSV file. However I notice it doesn't work
for some reason (The image is saved correctly but the csv is not saving). There is nothing wrong with the file i am uploading.
I just don't know how to save 2 kinds of file on same controller or model.
Any hints? Thanks in advance! Here is the generic view of my code

```
$image_config = array('path' => '/mypath/forimage',
                'randomize' => true,
                'ext_whitelist' => array('img', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'),
);

Upload::process($image_config);

if (Upload::is_valid())
{
    //save image
    Upload::save();
}


$csv_config = array('path' => '/mypath/forcsv',
                'randomize' => true,
                'ext_whitelist' => array('csv', 'txt'),
);

Upload::process($csv_config);

if (Upload::is_valid())
{
   //save csv
   Upload::save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Upload::process()` only one time.

> The process method processes the information about all uploaded files
>   http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/upload/usage.html#/method_process

And `Upload::save()` also save all validated uploaded files.